# Error when installing FreeIPA on CentOS

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, ipa, freeipa

I've gotten a message saying I've successfully installed FreeIPA on my CentOS machine, but when I try to log into it from my browser I get this message.

My host name is mike.imagine
So I typed in https://mike.imagine.com/ipa/ui/ and I get "400 Bad Request"[Flipping BS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psX61.png)

Comment: not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Firewall is turned off depending upon the version of your Centos version.

```
systemctl stop iptables
```

You should see below status messages

```
[sample@centos ~]$ sudo systemctl status iptables          
â— iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2017-08-08 14:41:06 EDT; 3 weeks 1 days ago
 Main PID: 10890 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 08 14:38:01 systemclt systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 firewall with iptables...
Aug 08 14:38:01 systemclt iptables.init[10890]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Aug 08 14:38:01 systemclt systemd[1]: Started IPv4 firewall with iptables.
Aug 08 14:41:06 systemclt systemd[1]: Stopping IPv4 firewall with iptables...
Aug 08 14:41:06 systemclt iptables.init[11013]: iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter [  OK  ]
Aug 08 14:41:06 systemclt iptables.init[11013]: iptables: Flushing firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Aug 08 14:41:06 systemclt iptables.init[11013]: iptables: Unloading modules: [  OK  ]
Aug 08 14:41:06 systemclt systemd[1]: Stopped IPv4 firewall with iptables.
```